# insert tokenized strings from a table to other

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Write down SQL statement to insert Student table’s data into MM_Student with the following guide lines:

*FullName* is consists of three names partitions such that

*FirstName:* First word on the left side of FullName before first space character

*MiddleName:* Second and third words from left side of FullName (if exist)

*FamilyName:* Last word of a FullName always be cosidered as a Family or LastName.

Every name must contain Family Name.

```
create table Student
(StuId CHAR(9),
FullName VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
Address VARCHAR2(20),
City VARCHAR2(15),
PostalCode VARCHAR2(6),
Constraint PK_Stuid PRIMARY KEY (StuId)
);



create table MM_Student
(StuId CHAR(9),
FirstName VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
MiddleName VARCHAR2(20),
FamilyName VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
Address VARCHAR2(20),
City VARCHAR2(15),
PostalCode VARCHAR2(5),
Constraint PK_Stuid PRIMARY KEY (StuId)
);
```

Comment: Is it SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: First of all you need to which DBMS you are using. Secondly nobody is going to do your homework for you. This is painfully obvious it is an assignment. And more importantly, you haven't even asked a question. You just posted a bunch of information.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @ErayBalkanli it is oracle, I am new at sql i need help in making tokens of fullname into first,second and third. Thanks

Comment: @SeanLange  thanks for response but its a random assignment from the internet which i am trying to solve, i hope you'd rather avoid judging if you are not in a mood of extending your help.

Comment: @jarlh thanks for the response you can read upper comment.

Comment: @learningsql - Sean Lange has a point. This site is not for solving your assignments if you don't show your own work; even if it's a random assignment off the web. Show what YOU tried and where YOU encountered difficulties.

Comment: On the contrary, I did not judge anything. I was quite objective in my understanding of your question at the time of my comment. The fact that I wanted to help is why I said anything at all. The answer was not clear at that point because syntactically sql server and oracle are very different on this type of thing. Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If FULLNAME always consists of 3 parts (which is what you said), then it is relatively simple, using the `REGEXP_SUBSTR` regular expression function:

```
SQL> with test (fullname) as
  2    (select 'Metro Goldwyn Mayer' from dual
  3    )
  4  select regexp_substr(fullname, '\w+', 1, 1) first_name,
  5         regexp_substr(fullname, '\w+', 1, 2) middle_name,
  6         regexp_substr(fullname, '\w+', 1, 3) last_name
  7  from test;

FIRST_NAME           MIDDLE_NAME          LAST_NAME
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
Metro                Goldwyn              Mayer

SQL>
```

No problem in doing it using *classic* `SUBSTR` + `INSTR` combination, but - that's not a *pretty* solution:

```
SQL> with test (fullname) as
  2    (select 'Metro Goldwyn Mayer' from dual
  3    )
  4  select substr(fullname, 1, instr(fullname, ' ', 1, 1) - 1) first_name,
  5         substr(fullname,
  6                instr(fullname, ' ', 1, 1) + 1,
  7                instr(fullname, ' ', 1, 2) - instr(fullname, ' ', 1, 1) - 1) middle_name,
  8         substr(fullname,
  9                instr(fullname, ' ', 1, 2) + 1) last_name
 10  from test;

FIRST_NAME           MIDDLE_NAME          LAST_NAME
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
Metro                Goldwyn              Mayer

SQL>
```

This is the first part of your task; write the INSERT statement yourself. If you can't make it work, edit your initial message, provide code you managed to work, explain what's wrong and someone will assist.